# convert js number to xxx xxx xxx ,xx?

Tags: javascript

I have an number I want convert its format to `xxx xxx xxx,xx`(will use for display in html page)

Example

```
1069.83
```

to

```
1 069,83
```

OR something like this

```
13761000.00
```

to

```
13 761 000,00
```

In JavaScript are the build-in function or the ways  to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your data pattern you can enhance this function: ( see it here : http://jsfiddle.net/DSJuL/1/ )

```
var number = 13761000.00;

alert(formatNum(number));

function formatNum(number)
{
   var newNum = "";
   var oldNumStr = number + "";
   var done = 0;
   var parts = oldNumStr.split(".");
   var newPart1 = "";
   var newPart2 = parts[1];
   for(var j= parts[0].length -1 ;j >= 0;j--)
   {   
       newNum = parts[0][j] + newNum;
       done++; 
       if((done%3) == 0)
          newNum = " " + newNum;        
   }
   newNum = (newPart2)? (newNum + "," + newPart2) : newNum + ",00" ;
   return newNum;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If using jQuery is an option you can check the globalization plugin. It supports number formatting nicely. Check [this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-global#numbers) out.

If you can't use jQuery - check [this](http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/numberFormat.html).

Comment: I am not using jquery ,I am using JavaScript.

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library :)

Comment: have a look but I don't understand .from 1069.83 to 1 069,83  not 1,069.83